# How do I integrate nanoc and Twitter Bootstrap/Zurb Foundation?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, nanoc

I am making a fairly big website. Mostly on culture of a particular place.

1. Are static sites a good idea?
2. How do I integrate nanoc and some framework? There are a couple of github repos on this, but I wanted to this from scratch in order to learn. Otherwise, I am afraid I might not be able to fix something that goes wrong later.

PLease help~

Comment: Looks like Nanoc can play nicely with Rails:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nanoc/JTi4Z_OUmkw

Comment: You might also look at rails engines, since they let you embed other apps (rails or otherwise) in rails.

Comment: Before thinking about Bootstrap vs Foundation, I would think about the pros and cons of a CMS vs a static site. It seems to me, the more you go towards a 'fairly big website', the more you should think about using a CMS solution.

Comment: Thanks ! I am thinking of Mezzanine/Django instead now. If nothing else works, wordpress!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently decided to make a reasonably sized site using nanoc and Zurb Foundation myself, so I can tell you my thoughts on this:

1. A static site is a good idea in many situations, but they do have obvious limitations (with everything being static!). The typical use of a static generator like nanoc is for a blog, for which most of the limitations aren't a problem (especially with services like Disqus for comments). I personally decided to use nanoc to save hosting/maintenance costs initially (using Amazon S3 to host a static site is cheap and scalable compared to a VPS), because I don't need any of the dynamic stuff yet, and to learn something new!
2. I've written a few posts on my blog (link in my profile) about how I've integrated foundation from scratch with nanoc. I can't comment for bootstrap, but my steps were:

   - Use the [nanoc tutorial](http://nanoc.ws/docs/tutorial/) to create a site
   - Use [compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/integration/) to integrate foundation into your site, by creating a `compass.rb` that has a `require "zurb-foundation"` line as well as config for your asset paths (mine is [here](https://github.com/chickenboot/vintageinvite/blob/v1.0/compass.rb))
   - Run a `compass install foundation -c compass.rb` to populate the foundation stylesheets, images and javascripts into your asset directories
   - Update your `Rules` file to include compass, and process the stylesheets accordingly

That is a high-level overview - there's step-by-step detail on my blog if you're interested in going the foundation route.

Comment: Thanks. I am still struggling with it. I'll post some more questions.

Comment: Could you please link your Blog as well?

Comment: Sure - it's [here](http://chickenboot.com/2013/05/18/zurb-foundation-with-nanoc-part-1/). It's a bit rough around the edges, but hopefully it will help. Let me know if not!